# SMIL-Free solution for CSS animations on SVG copied elements

Tags: html, css, svg

After a couple days researching about SVG for Web, tryint to use SMIL but finally giving up (even though it's pretty awesome, Microsoft refuses to support it - even on Edge) and Google plans to drop it from chrome too..

So, I plan to do it with CSS animations.. it works almost perfectly, but there is a big issue: animations won't replicate to copies of an element, so I would have to re-create the element over and over on the page:

My Sampe Code:

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0%  {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}


@keyframes breathe {
  0%  {transform: scale(1)}
  50%  {transform: scale(1.1)}
  100% {transform: scale(1)}
}

#square1 {
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

#square2 {
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}


#squares {
  animation: breathe 3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h3>This is animated</h3>
<svg id="squares">
    <rect id="square1" x="10" y="20" fill="red" width="50" height="50"></rect>
    <rect id="square2" x="70" y="20" fill="darkred" width="50" height="50"></rect>   
    <rect id="square3" x="130" y="20" fill="black" width="50" height="50"></rect>
    <rect id="square4" x="190" y="20" fill="gray" width="50" height="50"></rect>
    <rect id="square5" x="250" y="20" fill="green" width="50" height="50"> </rect>   
</svg>
    </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Animations from parent element will not replicate into it's copies. <br>
        This should be animated, but it isn't :(</h3>
     <svg id="testb">
      <use xlink:href="#squares"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

No apparently this happens because the browser does not "refresh" the copied element according to the parent, the animation applies to the parent, but the copy just pulls one frame out of it. How could I make this work?

Comment: for your CSS selectors can you use the actually node type instead of an id? So `#squares` or `#squares1` would just become `rect { /*ani style here*/ }`

Comment: that could be used, yes, but still the effect won't copy to the second instance.

Comment: How are you making copies of you `rect`'s? via javascript? if so could you share that code? sorry if I am not understanding the problem correctly

Comment: the code is in the question as a snippet

Comment: Sorry, I am not really understanding the problem. What is your expected output from the code above? Do you not want the `rect`'s that are spinning to not have the breathe animation? _Animations from parent element will not replicate into it's copies._ do you mean "children" instead of "copies"? The word "copies" is confusing me I think lol, I see no code that is copying anything

Comment: this is a svg copy of the element: <use xlink:href="#squares"></use>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the rotation animations into classes.

```
.square1-rotate {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

.square2-rotate {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

.squareBreathe {
   animation: breathe 3s infinite;
}
```

and then adding this class to your "use" statement ala:

```
  <use xlink:href="#squares" class="squareBreathe"></use>
```

Untested by me!  Just a quick response.  And then

```
<rect id="square1" class="square1-rotate" x="10" y="20" fill="red" width="50" height="50"></rect>
```

to see if the  #square1 will rotate.  If not, you could try including a style attribute to square1 that references the animation.  Hope this helps.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try `<use>` with `<defs>` and `<animateTransform>`. NO CSS required either.

Note: Chrome rotates the first 2 boxes while FF skips the rotation. IE doesn't show anything. Perhaps best to use javascript coding to support all 3 browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h3>This is animated</h3>
<svg id="squares">
      <!-- list resourses in a <defs> element -->
    <defs>
        <rect id="my_rect"
            x="10" y="10"
            width="50" height="50"
           >

        </rect>
      
         <rect id="my_rect2"
            x="10" y="10"
            width="50" height="50"
           >

        </rect>     
      
    </defs>
  
<g >
    <use xlink:href="#my_rect" fill="red" >         <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
            values="0 35 35; 360 35 35"
            additive="sum"
            dur="1s"
            repeatCount="indefinite" /> </use>
    <use xlink:href="#my_rect" transform="translate(60,0)" fill="darkred" > <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
            values="0 35 35; 360 35 35"
            additive="sum"
            dur="1s"
            repeatCount="indefinite" /> </use>
    <use xlink:href="#my_rect2" transform="translate(120,0)" fill="black"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#my_rect2" transform="translate(180,0)" fill="gray" ></use>
    <use xlink:href="#my_rect2" transform="translate(240,0)" fill="green" > </use>  
  
          <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform" type="scale"
            values="0.9; 1; 0.9"
            dur="2s"
            repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </g>
</svg>
    </div>
  <div>
    <h3>
        This should be animated too</h3>
     <svg id="testb">
      <use xlink:href="#squares"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```